# Export textfield tags in XDP to XML: Adobe LC Designer / Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, acrobat, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have several XDP files (made with Adobe LiveCycle Designer). All of these XDP files have several textfields, and what I would like is to export each XDP file to an XML file that only contains the textfields in the XDP.

The reason is that when working on the backend and mapping up values to the textfields in the XDP, it would be a lot easier to just look at an XML with the available textfields than to switch back and forth between Eclipse and Adobe LC Designer.

Is it possible to do this from within Adobe LC Designer or Adobe Acrobat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your going about this the right way. I would open the xdp in (say) Ultraedit and use Find... (regular expression sorting out lines containing "

Anyway, here's your answer:

1. Open the xdp in LiveCycle
   Designer.
2. Make sure all objects
   are locked except fields
   (Edit->Lock...)
3. Select everything
   (by *drawing a rect using the
   mouse*, ctrl-a won't do the trick!)
4. ctrl-c
5. Start a new document in your favourite text editor.
6. ctrl-v.